# BootstrapTable create iterator warnings in React

Tags: reactjs, warnings, bootstrap-table, react-bootstrap-table

I am studying how to create Tables in React.js.
I have a simple code which takes a list (hardcoded) like this:

```
data = [{
      "item1": 0.0,
      "item1": 0.0,
      "item1": 0,
      "item1": 0.36363636363636365,
      "item1": "string",
      "item1": 0,
      "item1": "string",
      "item1": "string",
      "item1": 0.0,
      "item1": 0.2569125,
      "item1": 0.0625,
      "item1": 0.0521760194628226,
      "item1": 2,
      "item1": 0.0534268,
      "item1": 0.0,
      "item1": 1180.0,
      "item1": 0.0
    }];
```

and creates a DataTable object in render():

```
render() {


    return (
      <div>
        <DataTable data = {data}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

The class simply do as follows:

```
class DataTable extends Component {

    createColumnsArray() {
        var columns = [];
        for (var i in this.props.data) {
            var keysArr = Object.keys(this.props.data[i]);
            for (var index in keysArr) {
                var element = {};
                element.dataField = keysArr[index];
                element.text = keysArr[index];
                columns.push(element);
            }
        }

        return columns;
    }

    render() {
        var columns = this.createColumnsArray();

        return (
            <div className="Tables">
                <p className="Table-header">Country Statistics</p>
                <BootstrapTable keyField='id' data={ this.props.data } columns={ columns } />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default DataTable
```

By the way, the following warning appears on Chrome console:

```
index.js:2178 Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. See link for more information.
    in tbody (created by Body)
    in Body (created by BootstrapTable)
    in table (created by BootstrapTable)
    in div (created by BootstrapTable)
    in BootstrapTable
    in DataProvider (created by BootstrapTableContainer)
    in BootstrapTableContainer (at DataTable.js:27)
    in div (at DataTable.js:25)
    in DataTable (at App.js:43)
    in div (at App.js:39)
    in App (at index.js:9)
```

I really do not understand how to eliminate this warning.

Comment: What lib you are using, I don't see `columns` prop here http://allenfang.github.io/react-bootstrap-table/docs.html#propsOnBootstrapTable ?

Comment: using import BootstrapTable from 'react-bootstrap-table-next'

Answer (score 2):

Edit: You need to have an id property in your data array because you are referring to this `id` in the `keyField` prop.
Your data array should follow this structure:

```
data = [{
        "id": 1,
        "item1": 0.0,
        "item1": 0.0,
        "item1": 0,
        ...
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "item2": 0.36363636363636365,
        "item2": "string",
        "item2": 0,
        "item2": "string",
        ...
    }...];
```

Edit: Also just change the `keyField` in the component call: `<BootstrapTable keyField='item1' data={ this.props.data } columns={ columns } />` as you discovered.

Comment: Oh sorry, the id should be place in your data array. I'm going to edit the answer.

Comment: this works, thank you!

btw, what if I want to specify my own id (like one of the fields)? 
EDIT: discovered, just changed the "keyField" in the component call: 
<BootstrapTable keyField='item1' data={ this.props.data } columns={ columns } />

Comment: Yeah, you got the idea! But if you want to understand this in React, read this doc: [List and keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys)

Answer (score 0):

> <BootstrapTable keyField='id' data={ this.props.data } columns={ columns } />

1. keyField must be a datafield existes in data. i.e. 'id' is an existing column name in data.
2. each element in keyfield must be not null and unique. i.e. no duplicate value or null value within column 'id'.
3. each element in any displaying/hidden columns must be not null. e.g. column 'itme1' is the column needed to display. there shouldn't be null values within column 'item1'

so, ensure name of keyfield match to the name in datafield. cleaning the data by removing and/or converting null.