# React-Bootstrap-Table: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-bootstrap-table

I've been trying to create a react-bootstrap-table2 but I get the following warning: *Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.*

Here is my code:

```
export const columns = [
  {
    dataField: "timestamps",
    text: "Timestamp",
  },
];

class Table extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { timestamps: [] };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const database = db.ref().child("timestamped_measures");
    database.on("value", (ts_measures) => {
      const timestamps = [];
      const columns = [{ dataField: "timestamps", text: "Timestamp" }];
      ts_measures.forEach((ts_measure) => {
        timestamps.push(ts_measure.val().timestamp);
      });
      console.log(timestamps);
      this.setState((prevState) => {
        return { timestamps: [...prevState.timestamps, ...timestamps] };
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <BootstrapTable
          keyField="timestamps"
          data={this.state.timestamps.map((item) => ({ item }))}
          columns={columns}
          pagination={paginationFactory()}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Table;
```

[Here is the console with the list of data I am trying to display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtkCS.png)

So my question is how to give each child in a list an unique key.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BootstrapTable create iterator warnings in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51750381/bootstraptable-create-iterator-warnings-in-react)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing array of integers instead of array of objects that has "timestamp" property.

```
export const columns = [
 {
   dataField: "timestamp",
   text: "Timestamp",
 },
];

class Table extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = { timestamps: [] };
  }
  
componentDidMount() {
const database = db.ref().child("timestamped_measures");
database.on("value", (ts_measures) => {
  const timestamps = [];
  ts_measures.forEach((ts_measure) => {
    timestamps.push({ timestamp: ts_measure.val().timestamp });
  });
  console.log(timestamps);
  this.setState((prevState) => {
    return { timestamps: [...prevState.timestamps, ...timestamps] };
  });
});
}

 render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <BootstrapTable
          keyField="timestamp"
          data={this.state.timestamps}
          columns={columns}
          pagination={paginationFactory()}
         />
       </div>
    );
    }
  }
 export default Table;
```

Answer (score 2):

You `keyField` should be set to `dataField`(key) not `timestamps`(value). Also, no mapping of data is required.

https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/docs/table-props.html#keyfield-required-string

i.e.

```js
<BootstrapTable
   keyField="dataField"
   data={this.state.timestamps}
   columns={columns}
   pagination={paginationFactory()}
/>
```